# How to map properties to a columns

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Like I mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24958482/how-to-name-foreign-keys-with-database-first-approach), I wanted to rename some auto generated properties.

So I use the following partial class

```
    public partial class Plan
    {
        public Profile Creator
        {
            get { return this.Profile; }
            set
            {
                this.Profile = value;
            }
        }

        public Profile Guest
        {
            get { return this.Profile1; }
            set
            {
                this.Profile1 = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

to avoid using `Profile1` and `Profile`. It works but I can't use these new properties in a where clause because they are not mapped (well that's my guess).

Example:

```
myQuery.Where(x => x.Creator.User.UserName == userName)
```

I have the following exception

> The specified type member 'Creator' is not supported in LINQ to
>   Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation
>   properties are supported.

I tried to map the property like this but without any success

```
[Column("creator_id", TypeName="int")]
public Profile Creator
{
    get { return this.Profile; }
    set
    {
        this.Profile = value;
    }
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Can't you just rename the column in the EF designer?

Comment: I use partial class to avoid doing it every time I generate the model

Answer (score 0):

i think you are looking for something like this

```
  [ForeignKey("creator_id")]
  public virtual Profile Creator { get; set; }
```

These things you commonly use for a code first approach. If you have an existing database you can reverse engineer your code first. check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620.aspx for an example. That way you can use the fluent API toolkit and an existing database. the best of two worlds.

Comment: I think this is when you use the code first approach?

Comment: yes you are right, updated answer to show how you can combine these two